# how to access a variable outside a for loop in swift

Tags: swift

```
do {
    let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

    for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
        var  savepassword = result.valueForKey("savePassword")!     
    }
} catch {

}

// what I want is to be able to access the variable out here
// savepasword
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `savePassword` outside the loop.  You should note that if there are multiple objects returned from your query then you will end up with the value from the last object in the array.   This may or may not be what you want

```
var savepassword : String?

do {
    let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

    for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
        savepassword = result.valueForKey("savePassword") as? String    
    }
} catch {

}

if let savepassword = savepassword {
   // Do something with savepassword
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `result.valueForKey("savePassword")` be casted to `String`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var any: Any
do {
    let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
    any = results
 } catch {

}
for result in any as! [NSManagedObject] {
    var  savepassword = result.valueForKey("savePassword")!
}
```